# understanding how to have one legend for a group plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I know this question has been asked in various forms before, but I just do not understand the syntax of one of the solutions that I would like to use. I have checked the documentation of Tikz and pfg plot to no avail, and I am hoping someone can clarify how this example works.

What I would like to do is have a 2row/1col group plot with the legend either to the right or underneath (but would like to try both to see what looks better if possible). Here is an example online from [PGFPlots - trying to combine legends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192729/pgfplots-trying-to-combine-legends) that does work.

My question comes down to not understanding some of the syntax here. The original question explained some of the syntax for the second \path command, but I am still confused. What do the arguments to the \path commands (first and second mean), why do anchor-south in the matrix command and what is the significance of the at[...]. If someone could clearly explain these things, that would be really great. I couldn't find resources online that made things clear to me.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 4},height=5cm,width=6.4cm]
        \nextgroupplot[title=type1,ylabel={Range1 }]
                \addplot[blue] {x};\label{plots:plot1}
                \addplot[red] {x^2};\label{plots:plot2}
                \addplot[green] {2*x};\label{plots:plot3}
                \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
        \nextgroupplot[title=type2]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range2 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range3 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads},ylabel={Range4 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads}]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
                \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (top-|current bounding box.west)-- 
          node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {throughput} 
          (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
      coordinate(legendpos)
      (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=south,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw
  ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
  {
    \ref{plots:plot1}& curve 1&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot2}& curve2&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot3}& curve 3\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might make more sense if you note that [midway] is the default for placing nodes and coordinates along paths. [anchor=south] means the same as [above] (which is left when rotated 90).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows how to put a 1 column legend on the right.  It occurred to me that your legend comes from one plot instead of combining entries from multiple plots, which simplifies matters.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 4},height=5cm,width=6.4cm]
        \nextgroupplot[title=type1,ylabel={Range1 },legend to name=zelda]
                \addplot[blue] {x};\addlegendentry{curve 1};
                \addplot[red] {x^2};\addlegendentry{curve 2};
                \addplot[green] {2*x};\addlegendentry{curve 3};
                \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
        \nextgroupplot[title=type2]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range2 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range3 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads},ylabel={Range4 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads}]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
                \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (top)--(bot) coordinate[midway] (group center);
    \node[above,rotate=90] at (group center -| current bounding box.west) {throughput};
    \node[right=1em,inner sep=0pt] at(group center -| current bounding box.east) {\pgfplotslegendfromname{zelda}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks! This helped clear things up for me. It is more intuitive than the example I had posted.