# pgfplots - tikz external - legends are missing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external, groupplots

I'm using tikz external to get plots rendered faster. But legends in the plots are missing if external is used.

**Update:** I'm using `label` to create legend. The same issue does not occur if `\legend` is used. I wanted to use `label` as it gives me more flexibility in groupplot. See question [PGFplots - single legend in a group plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192424/pgfplots-single-legend-in-a-group-plot)

main file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots,external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \input{sample.tikz}         % input TiKZ figure code
    \caption{legends missing in tikz external}  % caption
    \label{fig:sample}              % label
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

sample.tikz

```
% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset
{
    select coords between index/.style 2 args=
    {
        x filter/.code=
        {
                \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
                \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        }
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 1},height=4cm,width=4cm,max space between ticks=20,minor tick num=1,tick label style={font=\footnotesize}]
        \nextgroupplot[title={2K},xtick=data]
                \addplot[blue,dotted,mark=asterisk]         [select coords between index={0}{4}] table[x=threads,y=foo-MOPS,col sep=space]{Data/mic/threadSweep.csv};       \label{plots:foo:cka}
                \addplot[green, dotted,mark=o]              [select coords between index={0}{4}] table[x=threads,y=bar-MOPS,col sep=space]{Data/mic/threadSweep.csv};       \label{plots:bar:cka}
                \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
        \nextgroupplot[title={20K} ,xtick=data] 
                \addplot[blue,dotted,mark=asterisk]         [select coords between index={5}{9}] table[x=threads,y=foo-MOPS,col sep=space]{Data/mic/threadSweep.csv};  
                \addplot[green, dotted,mark=o]              [select coords between index={5}{9}] table[x=threads,y=bar-MOPS,col sep=space]{Data/mic/threadSweep.csv}; 
                \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
\end{groupplot}
    \path (top-|current bounding box.west)-- node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {\small system throughput} (bot-|current bounding box.west);
    \path (top|-current bounding box.north)-- coordinate(legendpos) (bot|-current bounding box.north);
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, anchor=south, draw, inner sep=0.2em, draw] at ([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
    {
        \ref{plots:foo:cka}&    foo         & [5pt]
        \ref{plots:bar:cka}&    bar         \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

output
[image]

Comment: We do not have your `threadSweep.csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [patch suggested  by Ijon Tichy](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/9476/labels-an-pgfplots/9527) on [TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/) (German) to externalize a `tikzpicture` using `\label` and `\ref` for the legend.

The following example is from [PGFplots - single legend in a group plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192433/43317) because I do not have the `threadSweep.csv`.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetexternalprefix{external_figs/}
\tikzset{external/up to date check=md5}% < added

%%% %http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/9476/labels-an-pgfplots/9527 (by Ijon Tichy)
\usepackage{scrlfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@lateexternal
\newcommand*{\nextwithlateexternal}{\@lateexternaltrue}
\renewcommand*{\@lateexternalfalse}{\global\let\if@lateexternal\iffalse}
% Den Systemaufruf von external so ändern, dass er optional doppelt
% stattfindet: Zunächst wie gehabt unmittelbar und zusätzlich nachdem
% die aux-Datei geschlossen (und sogar neu gelesen) wurde.
\patchcmd\tikzexternal@externalizefig@systemcall@@
  {\immediate\write18{\pgf@tempa}}%
  {\immediate\write18{\pgf@tempa}%
    \if@lateexternal
      \begingroup
        \protected@edef\reserved@a{%
          \noexpand\endgroup
          \noexpand\AfterReadingMainAux{%
            \noexpand\immediate\noexpand\write18{%
              \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\pgf@tempa}}%
          }%
        }%
      \reserved@a
    \fi
  }%
  {}%
  {\patchFailedError}
% Nun dafür sorgen, dass der Aufruf \nextwithlateexternal nur auf
% den nächsten potentiellen Systemaufruf von external wirkt statt
% auf den nächsten tatsächlichen oder gar alle:
\apptocmd\tikzexternal@externalizefig@systemcall@@
  {\@lateexternalfalse}
  {}
  {\patchFailedError}
\makeatother
%%%


\begin{document}

\nextwithlateexternal% < added
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 4},height=5cm,width=6.4cm]
        \nextgroupplot[title=type1,ylabel={Range1 }]
                \addplot[blue] {x};\label{plots:plot1}
                \addplot[red] {x^2};\label{plots:plot2}
                \addplot[green] {2*x};\label{plots:plot3}
                \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
        \nextgroupplot[title=type2]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range2 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range3 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads},ylabel={Range4 }]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads}]
                \addplot[blue]{x};
                \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (top-|current bounding box.west)-- 
          node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {throughput} 
          (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
      coordinate(legendpos)
      (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=south,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw
  ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
  {
    \ref{plots:plot1}& curve 1&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot2}& curve2&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot3}& curve 3\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Run twice.

Note: AFAIK this does not work with `latexmk`. And `\tikzset{external/force remake}` could only be used in the first run.

Comment: I can't compile this code, I get the following error: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \patchFailedError`. What am I missing?

Comment: The code in the answer patches an internal command. This internal command has been changed or was removed in newer `pgfplots` versions. Therefore the patch now fails. But the original issue has been fixed for a long time. So the patch is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the notes on use of `\label` and `\ref` in the **pgfplots** manual's section on externalisation. (Section 7.1 in my copy.)

You cannot use the default mode if you wish to combine these with externalisation. You need to use one of the available alternatives.

From page 473 of the **pgfplots** manual:

> For point a), a `\ref` inside of an externalized graphics works only
>   if you issue the required system call manually or by make. The initial
>   configuration `mode=convert with system call` does not support `\ref`.
>   But you can copy–paste the system call generated by `mode=convert with
>   system call` and issue it manually. The reason is that `\ref`
>   information is stored in the main `.aux` file – but this auxiliary
>   file is not completely written when `mode=convert with system call` is
>   invoked (there is a race condition). Note that `\pageref` is not
>   supported (sorry). Thus: if you have `\ref` inside of external
>   graphics, consider using `mode=list and make` or copy–paste the system
>   call for the image(s) and issue it manually.

Comment: how do i specify `mode=list`. I tried `\tikzset{external/mode list}` and `\tikzset{external/mode=list}`. They threw errors. Then I tried `\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]`. But the legend is still missing

Comment: Page 473: `/tikz/external/mode=list and make}`. So `\tikzset{/tikz/external/mode=list and make}` should be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime (with the `external` library of PGFPlots v1.14) it is sufficient to compile the following MWE twice to get the desired result ...

(I just deleted the middle two rows of plots in the MWE to save some space.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        matrix,
        pgfplots.external,
        pgfplots.groupplots,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
    \tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size= 2 by 2,
            },
            height=5cm,
            width=6.4cm,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[title=type1,ylabel={Range1 }]
            \addplot[blue] {x};\label{plots:plot1}
            \addplot[red] {x^2};\label{plots:plot2}
            \addplot[green] {2*x};\label{plots:plot3}
            \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
        \nextgroupplot[title=type2]
            \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads},ylabel={Range4 }]
            \addplot[blue]{x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads}]
            \addplot[blue]{x};
            \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
        \end{groupplot}
        \path (top-|current bounding box.west)--
              node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {throughput}
              (bot-|current bounding box.west);
        % legend
        \path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
              coordinate(legendpos)
              (bot|-current bounding box.north);
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes,
            anchor=south,
            draw,
            inner sep=0.2em,
        ] at ([yshift=1ex]legendpos) {
            \ref{plots:plot1}& curve 1&[5pt]
            \ref{plots:plot2}& curve2&[5pt]
            \ref{plots:plot3}& curve 3\\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code without whitespace]

Comment: I used part of this answer to answer a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445784/74459) which (currently) has an open bounty. Since it originally is your code, if you would like to add an answer there too, I could delete mine.

Comment: @Max, it is perfectly fine for me if you get the bounty :)

Comment: I can't compile this code, I get the following error: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \patchFailedError `. What am I missing?

Comment: @aaragon, sorry, but with an up-to-date MiKTeX I can still compile the code without any problems ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow I meant to put this comment in the accepted answer. Does that one compile for you?