# Custom legend order in pgfplots with externalization

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I'm struggling with getting a custom legend order in my pgfplots groupplot. I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282843/pgfplots-tikz-external-legends-are-missing) (esdd's answer) but I get the error `Undefined control sequence. {\patchFailedError}`

Stefan Pinnow says one answer later, that it should work the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{
    matrix,
    pgfplots.external,
    pgfplots.groupplots,
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}
    \tikzset{external/force remake} 
    \tikzsetnextfilename{ext}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size= 2 by 1,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                ylabels at=edge left,
                x descriptions at=edge bottom,
            },
            ]
            \nextgroupplot[]
            \addplot [color=black] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)};
            \addplot [color=red] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
            
            \nextgroupplot[name=aa]
            \addplot [color=black] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)}; \label{leg:a}
            \addplot [color=red] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)}; \label{leg:b}
            
        \end{groupplot}
    
\matrix [
matrix of nodes,
nodes={anchor=west},
anchor=north east,
at={([shift={(-3pt,-3pt)}]aa.north east)},
fill=white,
draw,
inner sep=2pt,
row sep=2pt
] {
    \ref{leg:b} $b$ \\
    \ref{leg:a} $a$ \\
};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I get this output:

[image]

Hence, the plot marks are missing. How can I achieve a custom legend order in my case? Disable externalization is no option (also not for this one plot).

Comment: off-topic: why you use ancient `pgfplots` (1.3)? Recent one is now 1.17 ...

Comment: I copy and pasted the header from the answer. I updated the version to 1.17 but it doesn't work either

Comment: There fore I said that the comment is "off-topic" :-)

Comment: When I compile your code I do not get your stated error. But I *also* get the `??`s instead of the lines. This is because of the `\tikzset{external/force remake} `. Remove this for the last compilation run and the lines appear.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I already figured that out too with the help of Excelsior's answer. Nevertheless it's annoying that `\tikzset{external/force remake}`  doesn't work properly then.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the position outside the `node` environment and then it works like expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,external}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}   
    \begin{figure}
        \tikzset{external/force remake} 
        \tikzsetnextfilename{ext}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group size= 2 by 1,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left,
                    x descriptions at=edge bottom,
                },
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[]
                \addplot [color=black] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)};
                \addplot [color=red] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
                
                \nextgroupplot[name=aa]
                \addplot [color=black] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)}; \label{leg:a}
                \addplot [color=red] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)}; \label{leg:b}
                
            \end{groupplot}
            
            \matrix [
            matrix of nodes,
            anchor=north east,
            fill=white,
            draw,
            inner sep=2pt,
            row sep=2pt
            ] at {([shift={(-3pt,-3pt)}]aa.north east)} {
                \ref{leg:b} & $b$ \\
                \ref{leg:a} & $a$ \\
            };
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I copied your code to a new file but I get the error `Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate. \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Steradiant Strange. Did you also copied the preamble? For me it is working as expected.

Comment: Yes, I copied everything. I figured out, that `\tikzset{external/force remake} ` makes problems. Without this command it works. The drawback is, that I always have to find the correct pdf-file to delete it if I want a remake.

Comment: @Steradiant maybe you can try `\documentclass{standalone}` (then you have to remove the `figure` environment) and have a look here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55760/override-tikz-externalize-up-to-date-flag)

Comment: With your code I cant reproduce showed result. MWE compile fine, but in result is no legend ...

Comment: That's no option for me. I have one TeX file which generates all graphics for a bigger main file. I don't want to make a full (or minimal) TeX file with preamble for every graphic.